# Message "Could not generate schema document" in WCF help page

Tags: c#, xml, json, wcf, auto-generate

I have a Rest API (WCF Net 4.0):

```
[ServiceContract]
interface ISubscriptionService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = Routing.ProductsRoute, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [Description("Получение информации о продуктах")]
    ProductsResult Products(string timestamp, string transaction_id);
}

[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
class SubscriptionService : ISubscriptionService
{
    public ProductsResult Products(string timestamp, string transaction_id)
    {
        SubscriptionProcessing processing = new SubscriptionProcessing();
        processing.SaveHistory(WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri);
        return processing.GetProducts(timestamp,  transaction_id);
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultEndPointBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="CloudWebAPI.SubscriptionService">
        <endpoint address="" kind="webHttpEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultEndPointBehavior" contract="CloudWebAPI.ISubscriptionService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Class ProductsResult:

```
[DataContract(Name = "result", Namespace = "")]
public class ProductsResult : CommonResult
{
    public ProductsResult()
    {
        Products = new List<ProductResult>();
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "products", Order = 3)]
    public List<ProductResult> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Class CommonResult:

```
[DataContract(Name = "result", Namespace = "")]
public class CommonResult
{
    public CommonResult()
    {
        TransactionId = string.Empty;
        Error = new ErrorResult();
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "transaction_id", Order = 1)]
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "error", Order = 2)]
    public ErrorResult Error { get; set; }
}
```

Class ErrorResult:

```
[DataContract(Name = "error", Namespace = "")]
public class ErrorResult
{
    public ErrorResult()
    {
        Code = 0;
        Message = string.Empty;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "error", Order = 1)]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "message", Order = 2)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Opening the page .../rest/SubscriptionService.svc/help/operations/Products, I get:

```
Message direction   Format  Body
Request N/A The Request body is empty.
Response    Unknown Could not generate schema document.
```

But if you change the attribute on the class ProductsResult **[DataContract (Name = "blabla", Namespace = "")]**, everything works fine:

```
Response    Xml Example,Schema
Response    Json    Example
The following is an example response Xml body:
...
```

What is the reason?

Comment: You've included a lot of code in there that seems to be irrelevant (You stated the problem is in Products result pretty much). You should remove unnecessary components of your question because right not it looks scary to click on

Comment: Thank you, when I tried to clean up the code, I realized the problem. The problem is the repetition of Name = "result" class inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

As ask125342 says in the comment above, classes cannot have the same Name decorator of a class that they inherit from - this will break the auto generation of WCF help pages.